# How do I ensure ssrs security using web api

Tags: c#, angular, reporting-services, webapi

We have an angular application on the client side, we use .net core web api on the back-end side. We used SSRS for the reporting system in our project. On the client side, we show these reports on the client using the ngx-ssrs-reportviewer module. My problem is that I want to check the identity and authorization of these users and show these reports accordingly, I need to prevent customers from seeing each other's information. I can also set up a new service, provide security with firewall, and only send requests from my api.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsdGj.png)

Comment: SSRS has security built in. Are you authenticating windows accounts? If not then there's nothing stopping anyone anonymous hitting the SSRS WEB API and runnign reports.

Comment: Im am using jwt bearer authentication in my web api. In my database i have field like userId that spesificies  that column to that user .i want  users to access only the reports of theirs(spesified by userId) and cant see the other usersreports. I dont know much about windows auth. If i use it would it be solving my problem?

Comment: From the docs here: https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer _SQL Server Reporting Services uses Windows Authentication to determine access to the reports_ SSRS doesn't know anything jwt bearer tokens. I'm guessing maybe your .Net core web back end may be authenticating with a single windows user. I'm not sure how `ngx-ssrs-reportviewer` authenticates to SSRS, but SSRS only supports windows authentication.